# nextDouble doesn't allow type int

Tags: java, random

quick question.

Why can nextDouble accept

```
1 + ( 900 - 1) * random.nextDouble()
```

but when I try to set it to

```
random.nextDouble((900 - 1) + 1) + 1);
```

it tells me nextDouble isn't applicable for the type int

Surely the first one is an int and it accepts that?

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Do you know how method invocation works? Have you read the javadoc for `nextDouble()`? How many arguments does it accept? Assuming you mean `java.util.Random`.

Comment: You're not sending any arguments to the first call.

Comment: if you want a random double from 1-900 inclusive then the first way you wrote it is correct.

Answer (score 7):

The [`Random` class's `nextDouble` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29) doesn't accept any arguments, so the second call will not compile.

Comment: Beat me to it hehehe.

Answer (score 0):

Because Java [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) does not expose a overloaded version of `nextDouble()` that accepts an upper limit like `nextInt(int n)` does for integers.

I would recommend Apache Commons Math [RandomDataGenerator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataGenerator.html)

```
RandomDataGenerator rdg = new RandomDataGenerator();
rdg.nextUniform(1.0, 900.0, true);
```

Or you can subclass `Random` and implement your own overloaded versions of `nextDouble`.

Answer (score 0):

`random.nextDouble((900 - 1) + 1) + 1);` Just think about it for a sec. It is a method call with parameters `(900 - 1) + 1) + 1` and [nextDouble()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29) doesn't accept any parameter hence your error. And BTW you are also missing one `opening brace` in second call.